# error en codigo

Tags: javascript

Hola a todos soy nuevo aqui. Hice este ejercicio con local storage donde el usuario ingresa elementos a la lista y si quiere puede borrar elementos de esta. y tambien puede poner un color opcional en el fondo de la lista escibiendo en la consola

nuevoColor("red");

el problema es que no cambia de color y marca error como se ve en la parte de la consola en la imagen[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por favor ayudenme y diganme que estoy haciendo mal ya lo intente todo. por favor. Aqui les dejo los codigos en js y html

JAVASCRIPT

```
'use strict'

window.addEventListener('load', () => {

    var NuevoFormulario = document.querySelector("#listaDePeliculas");

    NuevoFormulario.addEventListener('submit', function(){

        var lista = document.querySelector('#adregaPelicula').value;

        if(lista.length >= 1){
            localStorage.setItem(lista, lista);
        }

    });

    function nuevoColor(color){
        elementosDeLista.style.background = color;
        elementosDeLista.style.padding = "30px";
        elementosDeLista.style.color = "white";
    }


    var De = document.querySelector('#elementosDeLista');
    for(var h in localStorage){
        
        if(typeof localStorage[h] == 'string'){
            var ro = document.createElement("li");
            ro.append(localStorage[h]);
            De.append(ro);
        }
        console.log(localStorage[h]);
    }


    var BorrarFormulario = document.querySelector("#FormularioQuitarElementos");

    BorrarFormulario.addEventListener('submit', function(){

        var lista = document.querySelector('#QuitarPelicula').value;
    
        if(lista.length >=1){
            localStorage.removeItem(lista);
        }
    });
    


});
```

CSS

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>NOVIEMBRE-2-MIERCOLES</title>

</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="NOVIEMBRE-2-MIERCOLES.js"></script>

    <h1>NOVIEMBRE-2-MIERCOLES: Ejercicio de Local Storage </h1>
    <h2>El usuario llenara una lista y pondra un color opcional en el fondo de esta. En la consola escribira ejemplo nuevoColor(color);</h2>
    
    <form action="" id="listaDePeliculas">
        <input type="text" id="adregaPelicula" />
        <button type="submit">Guardar en la lista</button>
    </form>

    <h2>Lista de peliculas</h2>
    <div id="elementos">
        <div id="elementosDeLista">

        </div>
    </div>

    <h2>Borra tus elementos</h2>
    <form action="" id="FormularioQuitarElementos">
        <input type="text" id="QuitarPelicula" />
        <button type="submit">Borrar tus elementos</button>
    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Saca esa función del evento y supongo que te funcionará

Comment: mastergaru ya funciono bien lo saque del evento y ya funciona como yo quiero. Muchas Gracias